# How to convert non-utf8 encoding to utf-8 encoding during unzip?

Tags: encoding, zip, compression

I have the same problem which described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/872596/decompress-zip-with-given-encoding).

The only difference is I need to do this in MacOS.

Basically, all files are encoded in non-utf8 and zipped on Windows. When I unzip it on MacOS, they won't be readable at all. I need to convert the encoding to utf-8 during unzip.

I tried the command `unzip -O GB18030 gb18030.zip` which does not work on MacOS. I think it might because the unzip command in MacOS does not have the option `-O`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out [The Unarchiver.app](https://theunarchiver.com/) works.

Answer (score 0):

The [unzip you install from Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/unzip#default) supports the `-O` option.